# What is @. in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables

What is the `@.` variable in perl?

It appears be a special, writeable global, and (surprisingly) does not interpolate in double-quoted strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

                 # Under 5.8, 5.10, 5.12, 5.14, and 5.16,
                 # the following lines produce:

@. = (3, 2, 1);  # no error
print "@.\n";    # "@."
print @., "\n";  # "321"

eval 'my @.; 1'  # Can't use global @. in "my" at (eval 1)
  or die $@;     #  line 1, near "my @."
```

I couldn't recall ever encountering it before, and didn't see it in `perlvar` nor `perldata`.

Comment: This lack of interpolation is very wrong. Filed a [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=113792)

Comment: @ikegami: this behaviour is undocumented and so not wrong at all, never mind about *very wrong*. Programming languages are for people to use as tools: if you can find a programmer who has been inconvenienced by this anomalous behaviour then I raise my hat to you.

Comment: @Borodin, Interpolation is well documented, and this directly contradicts the documentation. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) states:

> Perl variable names may also be a sequence of digits or a single punctuation or control character. These names are all reserved for special uses by Perl;

and

> Perl identifiers that begin with digits, control characters, or punctuation characters are exempt from the effects of the package declaration and are always forced to be in `package main`; they are also exempt from `strict 'vars'` errors.

You are using a reserved name. You should not expect to be able to rely on any features.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't interpolate?

Comment: It's reserved by Perl. There is no reason to expect it to behave in any specific way.

Comment: Presumably, when `perl` is looking at `"@."`, it checks to see if `@.` is one of the variables which has special meaning. If not, it presumably assumes you did not mean to interpolate it. I am not sure exactly what kind of magic is needed for it to be interpreted differently, but I'd rather not venture there.

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW, I think a change here would break a lot of code that deals with the string representation of (naive) regexes to match email addresses, which is where I first saw this and wrongly thought, "oh, that'll interpolate to nothing."

Comment: It may well be that the Perl 5 porters made it immune from interpolation precisely because of this. But all this is speculation, and anything that isn't document is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`$.` is current line number (or record number) of most recent filehandle.

`@.` has no special meaning or use

---

`"@."` does not interpolate, but `"@{.}"` does.

`@.` is reserved for future use and should not be used

Comment: Yes. Does that then de facto declare, e.g., `%.` as well?  Why doesn't `@.` interpolate?

Comment: @pilcrow - Same as `@/`, `@~` and some other non-letter character array variables. You can use them as array, but they won't interpolate.

Comment: @pilcrow - Can be used as hash as well: `%~ = qw(1  2); print "$~{1}\n";` will print `2`

Comment: `@-` interpolates, I believe.

Comment: `@.` interpolates, but you have to write `"@{.}"`.

Comment: Interestingly, @- and @+ didn't interpolate in 5.6.1.

Comment: @ikegami - Are you digging back so far? How about `@{-}` and `@{+}` in 5.6.1 ?

Comment: @user1215106, I searched for existing tickets before filing one, and came across that. I don't have 5.6.1 to test with, but I bet that they would work.